# jQueryMobile + PhoneGap on iOS doesn't apply markup over ajax loaded content

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile app created using jquerymobile + phonegap. The Android version works great. I used the same html + css + javascript files for the iOS version. When I run the app in the XCode iPhone 6.0 simulator, all the jquery mobile elements are unstyled, and in the case of a listview with search, the search doesn't work. It is as if the jquery mobile plugins didn't run.

I load the content using ajax, and then trigger 'create' on the parent page element.

This is part of the index.html page. In the head part of the page, I load jquery, jquery mobile js and css:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/themes/mobiletheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <title>App Name</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myown.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="thepage">
   <div data-role="header">Header code here</div>
   <div data-role="content" id="thecontent">
       Content is loaded here using ajax
   </div>
   <div data-role="footer">Footer code here</div>
</div>
</body>
```

This is the part of the javascript that loads content with ajax and triggers create:

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'http://www.thedomain.com/thepage.php',
     dataType: 'html',
     type: 'GET',
     success:function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        $("#thecontent").html(data);
        $("#thepage").trigger('create');
     }
});
```

This works well in Android. But in iOS, it is as if the trigger('create') did nothing.

Has anyone experienced something like this? Any ideas on how to solve it will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Use $("#thepage").trigger('pagecreate');

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it and no change. Finally I found out the cause. The jquery mobile structure css had not been copied along with the rest of the files to the iOS development environment. Not sure why that happened, but when I copied the missing file, things started looking ok.